# How to make radius borders in android?

Tags: android

I want to make a radius like facebook story shape in my android app

I want the ImageView in my RelativeLayout to have a radius borders like facebook story shape , any help?

Answer (score 0):

> You have use image view inside cardview like...

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:id="@+id/card_view"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />

     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Send me the library to put in dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Create view like facebook story we have used card view .Please try this code

**Add this dependencies in gradle**

> implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

**xml Code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:gravity="center">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:src="@drawable/house1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]